# Optimize rails query deleting select method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am triying to optimize the following due to slow work on method *select* from ruby into more than 16.000 records, but i really dont know how to build it into SQL query or using joins and includes:

```
User.invited.not_rejected.order('users.updated_at desc').select{|x| x unless x.rtr.nil?}
```

The relations are:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  hass_many :transition_elements
  has_many :rtrs, through: :transition_elements

  scope :not_rejected -> { where(rejected: false) }
  scope :invited -> { where(invited: true) }
end

class TransitionElement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rtrs
  belongs_to :user
end

class Rtr < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :transition_element
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that a simple `joins(:rtrs)` should work because it is able to handle `has_many through` associations and builds an `INNER JOIN` that will only return users that have at least one `rtrs`.

```
User.joins(:rtrs).invited.not_rejected.order(updated_at: :desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to use `joins` like @spickermann suggests, you can compose multiple `ActiveRecord_Relation`s together:

```
users = User.not_rejected.invited.order(updated_at: desc)
users.where(rtrs: Rtr.all)
```

Or if you have a scope on `Rtr` you can use it:

```
class Rtr < ApplicationRecord
  scope :upside_down, where(upside_down: true)
end

users.where(rtrs: Rtr.upside_down)
```